# Triple count and groupby using MySql on a simple table... is it possible in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I'm having a question that can be explained using a simple fictive table.

Table "Drinks" has just three fields:

- Id (1..N) - Primary key
- Date ('2012-09-19'...) - Each date can occur very often
- Hot (1 for yes, and 0 for false).

I would like to produce a list like this:

```
    Date         Total    Hot    Cold
    2012-09-19   14       6      8
    2012-09-10   21       18     3
```

Etc.

The field "Cold" is as you might expect calculated as (Total - Hot).

What I've got so far is:

```
    SELECT Date, count(*) AS Total FROM Drinks GROUP BY Date;
```

This gives me the desired table, but of course without the columns "Hot" and "Cold".

Is there a way to modify my query so I can produce this table in one go? I can of course built the table in phases using PHP code, but that is probably not the elegant way nor the fastest.

I'm happy to watch and learn... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Date,
    count(*) AS Total,
    SUM(Hot = 1) Hot,
    SUM(Hot = 0) Cold
FROM Drinks
GROUP BY Date;
```

Comment: Wow! With the speed of light! As your solution is the most concise, I consider yours the best. I would have given you a point - but apparently my account does not allow me to do so yet, sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add `CASE` statements in your `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT Date, 
       count(*) AS Total,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Hot = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totlHOT,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Hot = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalCold
FROM Drinks 
GROUP BY Date;
```